# What pvp activities will give XP?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

When in a battleground, what things will grant experience? At my current low level, killing a player doesn't seem to give anything. Capping a flag in WSG or a base in AB will. Anyone know of anything else?
All in all, it seems to be really slow, like 10% of a level in a 20 min BG. Will this improve when I get to higher level?

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid that the only way to accumulate experience points through PVP is to accomplish objectives in Battlegrounds (honourable kills are **not** included). To answer your second question the XP you gain will likely increase in proportion with your level however it is also likely that the time in PVP needed to advance another level will increase as per the Higher level = Increased time questing to advance to the next level.

Hope this helps

Comment: Arathi basin is the best for xp as capping towers gives the best xp from any battleground (I was getting around 48k at one point) and with the other benefits of gaining honour and honourable kills at the same time

Comment: I personally found that Alterac Valley was *by far* the fastest source of XP because every tower cap was worth XP in addition to the general kill. Arathi Basin was a tiny fraction by comparison for a longer running match. They may have rebalanced it since I leveled that way however, because it's so much slower than questing now I haven't done it in several months.